# Difference between prop in obj and obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) and obj[prop]?

Tags: javascript

Should I use one over the other? Is using them all together better? Thanks.

Comment: [MDN in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/in), [MDN hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), [MDN Member Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

Comment: Updated links: [MDN `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in). [MDN `hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty). [MDN Member Operators, Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- `prop in obj` checks whether `obj` has a property named `prop` at all, even if it's just inherited from a prototype.
- `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)` checks whether `obj` *itself* holds a property named `prop`; it ignores properties inherited from prototypes.
- `obj[prop]` gets the value of the `prop` property.

Use whichever one is appropriate for what you're trying to accomplish

*Note*: In all three cases, `prop` must be a string.

Comment: can you please tell me if there is a difference between obj.prop and obj['prop']?  SLaks

Answer (score 1):

Just to give an example for this:

```
var animal = {"legs": 4};
var dog = {"barks" : true};
dog.__proto__ = animal;    // JS inheritance (dog inherits from animal)
```

now this means that:

```
console.log("legs" in dog);    // TRUE - due to JS inheritance and since 'in' key looks into inherited prototypes
console.log(dog.hasOwnProperty("legs"));    // FALSE
console.log(dog.hasOwnProperty("barks"));    //TRUE
```

prints

```
true
false
true
```

Note one more thing: If dog had "legs" property of lets say 5 (hhmm spooky i know), so the 'in' operator ("legs" in dog) will refer to the "legs" property which is declared in the dog object and not the inherited "legs" which comes from animal object. e.g.:

```
var animal = {"legs": 4};
var dog1 = {"barks": true};
var dog2 = {"barks": true, "legs": 5};
dog1.__proto__ = animal;
dog2.__proto__ = animal;

console.log(dog1.legs);
console.log(dog2.legs);
console.log("legs" in dog2) // 'in' refer to the un-inherited "legs" of dog2
```

prints

```
4
5
true
```